# How to optimize if statement in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, aws-lambda

After declaring two variables `param01` and `param02` I go ahead and check if the incoming `event.pathParameters` is not `undefined`:

```
      let param01, param02;

      if (event.pathParameters!=undefined) {
        if (event.pathParameters.param01!=undefined) {
          param01 = event.pathParameters.param01;
        }
        if (event.pathParameters.param02!=undefined) {
          param02 = event.pathParameters.param02;
        }
      }
```

While it works fine, it takes 10 lines of code. I wonder if there is a shorter and more elegant way of getting it done in Typescript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
const param01 = event.pathParameters && event.pathParameters.param01 || null;
const param02 = event.pathParameters && event.pathParameters.param02 || null;
```

or using just one line:

```
const { param01, param02 } = event.pathParameters || {};
```

If your environment allows, you can also use [Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

```
const param01 = event.pathParameters?.param01; // value or undefined
const param02 = event.pathParameters?.param02; // value or undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [the `?` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining)

```
let param01 = event.pathParameters?.param01 || null;
let param02 = event.pathParameters?.param02 || null;
```